# What is the propper way to get the active Grease Pencil object from code?

Tags: grease-pencil, properties, operator

Newbie here trying to understand better how things work.

I'm making a `GreasePencil` addon, and I need to access the active grease pencil object a lot. I accessed it in all my operators like:

```
context.gpencil
```

The problem is that, now that I'm making some shortcuts, instancing some panels, etc., most of my operators dont work. They gave me the error:

```
Context object has no attribute 'gpencil'
```

I used context.gpencil since I thought it was the "safest" way to access the GPencil (since, well, it was its own property in context). In addition, all my OTs have in their `poll()` to return `False` if the object is not a `GPencil`.

As I saw in the API, gpencil property is only in button context. So, when calling that same operator without using the button, dont works.

That got me wondering what was the propper way to access the GPencil.

Should I ignore that `.gpencil` and by default and use context.active_object and manually check if its a GreasePencil type?

Sorry if maybe is a silly question. But I don't understand why is that `.gpencil` property in context but only in a button context (I mean, makes no sense to me since we could try to access .gpencil in a non GreasePencil-related OT and it return None). Just wanted to be sure.

Thank you so  much for the help.

Comment: I get the exact same error with `override = bpy.context.copy()`, even though I'm not working with greasepencil at all.